# MongoDB update using seralized object in C#

Tags: mongodb, serialization

In my Application currently I am issuing two commands, one is Save to save serialized bson object and other is to update the date field using CurrentDate operator.

I am trying to enhance the performance by performing these two tasks in single command. I am thinking to use update command to perform this. My question is do we have any method to directly pass serialized object to the update command or do I need to explicitly use set operator for each field?

Thanks!
Vibhu

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the $currentDate operator and pass in a full object at the same time. However, why do you need to use the $currentDate operator if you are saving an object? Why not just set the CurrentDate on your object before saving?

```
obj.CurrentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
collection.Save(obj);
```

Comment: I cannot get date using DateTime.UtcNow, as it differs from the server date time. Anyways I have managed to do it different way by just adding update method. Thanks!

Comment: It would only differ if your servers were out of sync. Yes, they may be a second off, but that's probably not enough to matter. Utc time is the same everwhere.